# How to prevent video recording being stopped on incoming call?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I am using CameraX to record video in my app. Usually video capture takes 15-20 minutes and we have controls in app to pause and resume video capture. Now the issue I am facing is, when an incoming call comes, video capture stops instead of pausing. If the video capture stops user will have to retake the video again and it is a huge inconvenience. If it pauses, user can resume it after call. Is there any callbacks I can get in app when an incoming call comes, so that i can manually set the video capture to pause mode? Or is there any other possibilities?

Update:
When I tried solution(deprecated code) provided by Hazy Ziv , I am able to get callback of incoming calls and setting the video to Paused state there. But the moment call is attended, I am getting VideoRecordEvent.Finalize callback from CameraX. So regardless of whether I paused the video or not, video capture stopped and URI is returned :(

Answer (score 0):

TelephonyManager handles incoming calls

in your video activity register event listener

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // Incoming call: Pause video capture here
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // No call: Resume video capture here if it was paused
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // A call is dialing, active or on hold
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

dont forget to unregister the listener

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}
```

jetpack compose

```
@Composable
fun ListenToPhoneState(onCallStateChanged: (Int, String) -> Unit) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val telephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager

    val currentOnCallStateChanged by rememberUpdatedState(onCallStateChanged)

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val phoneStateListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
            override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String) {
                currentOnCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber)
            }
        }

        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)

        onDispose {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE)
        }
    }
}
```

listen in your Ui

```
@Composable
fun YourScreen() {
    ListenToPhoneState { state, phoneNumber ->
        when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                // Incoming call: Pause video capture here
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                // No call: Resume video capture here if it was paused
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                // A call is dialing, active or on hold
            }
        }
    }

    // Your other composables and UI elements
}
```

Comment: In compose how can we do it?

Comment: added compose to the original answer

Comment: Observed that if I am not recording the video and just in Camera, it works fine but while recording the callback doesn't come.

Comment: sorry cant help you there, you need to debug your app see why the listener not working while video works.

Comment: PhoneStateListener callback works even if its recording, but as its deprecated I used TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener . Here if the call comes during recording, then callback doesnt work.